# Error while inserting data in the sql server database using vb.net

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, sqlcommand

I'm using the following code to insert the data in a table and i am getting the error at cmd.executenonquery()....The exception is labelled as SQL exception and the underlying message says "String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated."

```
        Dim str As String  ' defines str as a string variable

        'takes insertion query as a string in str variable
        str = "Insert into Instructors Values(@inst_id, @inst_name, @contact, @game, 'N/A', 'N/A', 'Available')"

        'defines a new command which takes query string and connection string as parameters
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(str, con)

        ' defines Instructor ID parameter and takes its value from the form 
        Dim prmInstID As New SqlParameter("@inst_id", SqlDbType.Int)
        prmInstID.Value = TxtInstID.Text

        ' defines Instructor Name parameter and takes its value from the form 
        Dim prmInstName As New SqlParameter("@inst_name", SqlDbType.Char)
        prmInstName.Value = TxtInstName.Text

        ' defines Contact parameter and takes its value from the form 
        Dim prmContact As New SqlParameter("@contact", SqlDbType.VarChar)
        prmContact.Value = MskdTxtCntctno.Text


        ' defines Specialty Game parameter and takes its value from the form 
        Dim prmGame As New SqlParameter("@game", SqlDbType.VarChar)
        prmGame.Value = Me.ComboBox1.SelectedItem

        cmd.Parameters.Add(prmInstID)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(prmInstName)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(prmContact)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(prmGame)


        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        con.Close()
```

Comment: What values are you testing with `TxtInstID.Text`, `TxtInstName.Text`, `MskdTxtCntctno.Text`, and `Me.ComboBox1.SelectedItem`?

Answer (score 0):

This exception usually occures when your text field in the database is too small to fit the data you want to insert. For example if the instructor name field in the database has a length of 10 (characters) and the text from `TxtInstName.Text` has more than 10 characters, you will get this error.

To solve this you can make the field in the database bigger or check inside your form that the text is not too long.

Answer (score 0):

As aKzen said the error message is probably because you are trying to insert something which is too long to fit in one of your fields.

I just thought I would add to this some pointers as I would assume you are still learning etc. If you use stored procedures you could cut down your code a lot, and also increase the efficiency of your application.

Stored Procedures give you a few benefits, they are more secure as you are not transmitting query across the network (if someone intercepts your query they can gain knowledge about your table structure) Also Stored procedures do not have to be recompiled every time they are executed unlike passing a query string where the server has to compile the query each time it receives it. Also using a SP lets you reuse the same query in multiple places without having to copy paste your queryString.

Below is the way I would approach writing the code.

```
' Declare a new command
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand

' Set the type to Stored Proc and Tell it which connection to use
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmd.CommandText = "spMySpNameGoesHERE"
cmd.Connection = con

' Add the parameter and its value
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParamName",TxtInstID.Text ) 
' More Params go here

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() 

con.Close() 


CREATE PROCEDURE spMySpNameGoesHERE
(
@inst_id INT,
@inst_name VARCHAR(50),
etc etc
)
AS
BEGIN

Insert into 
Instructors 
Values(@inst_id, @inst_name, @contact, @game, 'N/A', 'N/A', 'Available')        

END
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is because you are entering larger number of characters in one or more fields than the size of DB table columns.

for example if you have a name column in a table with VARCHER(10) data type and length.
If you enter more than 10 characters in name column then you will receive this error.

Solution:
increase the length of column. e.g 25 or up to your requirement.
and
restrict number of characters in your text box saying `MaxLength="25"` if it is a textbox.